# Get default zone / region

Tags: go, google-cloud-sdk

I'm using the Golang google-cloud-sdk to get informations on resources (specifically here compute instances, but it doesn't really matter).

The `gcloud` cli allows to do something like this:

```
gcloud config set compute/zone ZONE
```

Which under the hood will write in `~/.config/gcloud/configurations/config_default` those value as something that looks like an ini file.

Can the (go) sdk read config those config file ?

The cli also read the environment variable `CLOUDSDK_COMPUTE_ZONE` if not defined in the config file.

Can the sdk also read this variables ?

To sum up the question , how can I use the same config mechanism the gcloud cli uses with the Go sdk ?

Comment: what prevents you from reading that file in the golang directly ?

Comment: Nothing prevents me, I'm just using an SDK to not reimplement the logic the provider provides. For example, both the aws cli (python) and the sdk (both python and go) , read AWS_PROFILE , AWS_ACCESS_KEY ...

Comment: Ach okay, seems legit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To sum up the question , how can I use the same config mechanism the gcloud cli uses with the Go sdk ?

As far as I know, you can't. You need to specify the zone to all your operations.
Long time ago, someone asked about `CLOUDSDK_CONFIG` and the last response is cristal clear:

> Resolved: we decided not to honor CLOUDSDK_CONFIG, in the interest of maintaining simplicity for the ADC spec.
>
> https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/issues/288

And I think it's true for all the `CLOUDSDK_*` env.